# MutationObserver not detecting additional table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use MutationObserver to check for new rows being added inside of a table, the code I've got below seems to work for H2 elements, however when I change this to Table rows, the console.log doesn't output to the console, if i inspect the table, the TR's are being added. Does anyone have any ideas? I can't figure out why it wont observe table row's being added

```
var list = document.getElementById("testtable");

var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver ||
    window.WebKitMutationObserver || 
    window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {  
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
           console.log("mutation!");
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(list, {
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
});

var element = ("tr");


setInterval(
    function(){ 
        $(list).append("<h2>" + "THIS IS A TEST" + "</h2>");
        //This doesn't work
        //$(list).append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<h2>" + "THIS IS A TEST" + "</h2>" + "</td>" + "</tr>");
    }, 
    2000);
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggwb2ejy/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the `subtree` option to true

```
observer.observe(list, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

When you add a `tr` it is not directly added to the `table` it is added to a `tbody` element, so in reality a subtree of the observed element is modified. To observe any changes in the subtree you need to set `subtree: true` in the configuration

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vz160w40/)